# Display access table records in a datagridview with custom column names

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns added in the property. How would I display the data from an access table to its assigned columns? (Column Names from the access should not be displayed)

```
cmd = cn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Course, Condensed FROM tblOTrainings WHERE @OJobLevel BETWEEN LowerBound AND UpperBound"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OJobLevel", .txtOJobLevel.Text)


            Dim table As New DataTable("tblOTrainings")
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(table)
            .dgOTraining.DataSource = table

            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                .dgOTraining.Rows.Add()
                With frmPersonalTraining.dgOTraining.Rows(frmPersonalTraining.dgOTraining.Rows.Count - 1)
                    .Cells("oCourse").Value = dr("Course")
                    .Cells("oCondensed").Value = dr("Condensed")
                End With
            Next
```

Comment: change the `HeaderText` of the columns

Comment: hello, in which part should I change it? By the way I have columns and the 3rd column is a datagridcombobox. only 2 columns from the access table must be displayed i the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.dgOTraining.DataSource = table
.dgOTraining.Columns("oCourse").HeaderText = "Course"
.dgOTraining.Columns("oCondensed").HeaderText = "Condensed"
.dgOTraining.Columns("oOther").Visible = False
```